# Akka HTTP 2.0 to use SSL (HTTPS)

Tags: scala, ssl, akka, akka-http

I am trying to add a self signed certificate to my configuration in order to make my web service to serve content over SSL but I had no luck.

Here is my current configuration

```
ssl {
  jksKeystore = "localhost.p12"
  password = "changeit"
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm misisng to be able to spin up an HTTPS server ?

My project is using akka 2.0 and scala

Comment: There is a section about server size HTTPS in the documentation: [Server-Side HTTPS Support](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/2.0.2/scala/http/low-level-server-side-api.html#server-side-https-support)

Comment: I am recommend using apache or nginx as a https proxy server. It is faster (due C++ implementation) and often upgraded (due popularity)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are some tests in the akka code base that test the https functionality. They use the predefined http contexts defined in [ExampleHttpContexts](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/f008a932c381013f6060ee00a731862bafed2be7/akka-http-core/src/test/scala/akka/http/impl/util/ExampleHttpContexts.scala).

I have created a small repo that uses the keys from the akka repository (I hope they won't mind) and creates a minimal https server using a self-signed certificate [here](https://github.com/rklaehn/akkahttpsserver). Done as a repo instead of as a gist so you can just clone it to get started.

Here is the scala code:

```
package httpsserver

import java.security.{SecureRandom, KeyStore}
import javax.net.ssl.{KeyManagerFactory, SSLContext}

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.{HttpsContext, Http}
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer

object Server extends App {

  val serverContext: HttpsContext = {
    val password = "abcdef".toCharArray
    val context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    val ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")
    ks.load(getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("keys/server.p12"), password)
    val keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
    keyManagerFactory.init(ks, password)
    context.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers, null, new SecureRandom)
    // start up the web server
    HttpsContext(context)
  }

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("server")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  import system._

  val route = Route(complete("ok"))

  Http().bindAndHandle(route, interface = "0.0.0.0", port = 8081, httpsContext = Some(serverContext))
}
```

Comment: That's awesome, it's a pity that there's no official example in the akka-http documentation.

Comment: The akka-http docs leave a lot to be desired. I hope this will improve once akka-http is integrated with akka 2.4.

Comment: Do you have any idea when that will happen? (any official words on that)

Comment: Shouldn't take much longer: http://akka.io/news/2016/01/26/akka-2.4.2-RC1-released.html

Comment: I've created a server similar to this example https://github.com/J-Technologies/akka-http-java/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/ordina/java/akkahttp/Server.java I'm wondering if the solution here to add SSL contradicts it and I need to rewrite my application or I can work them together

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn If you leave out the `clientAuth` parameter when creating `HttpsContext` the server will accept just any connection that goes at `https://` . It doesn't validate any client certificate.