# Enabling secure web socket support in Akka HTTP

Tags: scala, websocket, akka-http

How to enable support for secure web socket in Akka HTTP version 2.0.* ? I was not able to find any specific directive for this or any hints in the official documentation, please help.

My current approach is the following:

```
val handler:Flow[Message, Message, Unit]

val route:Route = path("ws") {
  get {
    handleWebsocketMessages(wsService(wsHandlerProps))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to first configure an akka-http web server (with a self-signed certificate for testing), and then use web sockets exactly like you have done.

I have pushed an update to my [self-signed secure server demo](https://github.com/rklaehn/akkahttpsserver/commit/cd6ee5886b0cac9fa88f1d0d6fc39834678191c9) that adds a web socket. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992456/akka-http-2-0-to-use-ssl-https).

One thing to be aware of is that you need to add the self-signed certificate to the list of accepted certificates of your browser. Otherwise the websocket connection will fail silently, because the browser will not pop up a dialog every time you connect to an untrusted secure websocket.

Another thing to keep in mind is that in your client side javascript or whatever code you need to use `wss://` instead of `ws:/`.

Answer (score 1):

As Rüdiger mentions, you need to get a certificate first. I stored mine in a KeyStore, which was the only way I could get akka-http to load it.

Once you have a cert, you need to configure an Https context:

```
 def getSSLContext() : HttpsConnectionContext = {

    val ks: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS")

    val keystorePath = config.getString("keystore.path")
    val keystorePassword = config.getString("keystore.password").toCharArray

    val keystore: InputStream = Files.newInputStream( Paths.get(keystorePath))

    require(keystore != null, "Keystore required!")
    ks.load(keystore, keystorePassword)

    val keyManagerFactory: KeyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
    keyManagerFactory.init(ks, keystorePassword)

    val tmf: TrustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509")
    tmf.init(ks)

    val sslContext: SSLContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS")
    sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers, tmf.getTrustManagers, new SecureRandom)
    ConnectionContext.https(sslContext)
  }
```

Then set it as the default:

```
Http().setDefaultServerHttpContext(getSSLContext())
```

Once that's done, you can bind your route and start handling requests:

```
  val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(api.route, bindAddress ,port=bindPort)

  bindingFuture.onComplete(println)
```