# Akka HTTP server with SSL support in Java - How to create configuration?

Tags: java, ssl, akka, tls1.2, akka-http

I am trying to create an Akka HTTP server, which will support SSL.

I am aware of this question for scala [Akka HTTP 2.0 to use SSL (HTTPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992456/akka-http-2-0-to-use-ssl-https) and I am trying to work it into Java code but I am getting lost.

The DSL akka.http.javadsl.Http class is different for Java and requires akka.actor.ExtendedActorSystem, when I try to create an instance for it I am required to create an application configuration with the com.typesafe.config.Config class, which I can't figure out how to instantiate and what to put in it.

Is there any simpler way? Or any classes I can use to create all the required configurations?

This is a snippet of the code:

```
    // boot up server using the route as defined below
    final ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create();
    final ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);

    // Run the server bound to the local machine IP
    String hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

    // No implementation here?????
    Config applicationConfig = new Config() {
    }
    ExtendedActorSystem extendedActorSystem = new ActorSystemImpl("HttpProxy", applicationConfig, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(), Option.empty());
    // todo: missing handler, settings, httpsContext and log
    Flow<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, ?> handler;
    ServerSettings settings;
    akka.japi.Option<HttpsContext> httpsContext;
    LoggingAdapter log;
    new Http(extendedActorSystem).bindAndHandle(handler, hostAddress, PORT, settings, httpsContext, log, materializer);

    System.out.println("Starting server on " + hostAddress + ":" + PORT);

    // The server would stop if carriage return is entered in the system cosole
    System.out.println("Type RETURN to exit");
    System.in.read();
    system.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supposed to be something like this:

// boot up server using the route as defined below

```
// Run the server bound to the local machine IP
String hostAddress = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();

// No implementation here?????
Config applicationConfig = ConfigFactory.load();
ActorSystem system =  ActorSystem.create("HttpProxy", applicationConfig);
final ActorMaterializer materializer = ActorMaterializer.create(system);


// todo: missing handler, settings, httpsContext and log
Flow<HttpRequest, HttpResponse, ?> handler;
ServerSettings settings;
akka.japi.Option<HttpsContext> httpsContext;
LoggingAdapter log;
Http.get(system).bindAndHandle(handler, hostAddress, 9000, settings, httpsContext, log, materializer);

System.out.println("Starting server on " + hostAddress + ":" + 9000);
```