# Redirect Akka HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: scala, https, akka-http

Currently I have an API that works for both HTTP and HTTPS, but I need it to just route to HTTPS even if the URL is called using HTTP. For example, both are working:

```
http://app1_0.cloud.example.net/getSomething
https://app1_0.cloud.example.net/getSomething
```

There is something in the Akka docs about adding `httpscontext` for certificates, but I'm not sure I need to do that because I already have HTTPS working. This is where the route it being called:

`Http().bindAndHandle(aliveResponse ~ route, host, port)`

The `host` and `port` are defined in the `application.conf`.

Is there a way to just add a redirect or a cast to make sure it sent to HTTPS?

A route example:

```
def marketsRoute = {
   pathPrefix("markets") {
     pathEnd{
       logRequestResult("Read markets", akka.event.Logging.InfoLevel) {
       get {
            implicit val timeout = Timeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

         val sitesResp = WaitListDAO.getMarkets
         complete(HttpResponse( entity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/json`, sitesResp.toJson.toString)))

         }
        }
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

Going to give this a shot with the answer:

```
def marketsRoute = {
    scheme("http") {
      extract(_.request.uri) { uri =>
        redirect( uri.withScheme("https"),
          StatusCodes.MovedPermanently
        )
      }
    } ~
   pathPrefix("markets") {
     pathEnd{
       logRequestResult("Read a waitlist enable markets", akka.event.Logging.InfoLevel) {
       get {
            implicit val timeout = Timeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

         val sitesResp = WaitListDAO.getMarkets
         complete(HttpResponse( entity = HttpEntity(MediaTypes.`application/json`, sitesResp.toJson.toString)))

         }
        }
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Akka HTTP 2.0 to use SSL (HTTPS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992456/akka-http-2-0-to-use-ssl-https)

Comment: No, i don't think so. As I said in the original question I don't think I need httpsContext which that answer relies on.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the HTTPS server is also being `bindAndHandle`-ed in the same app, you shouldn't need to define `HttpsConnectionContext`.

The route for HTTPS redirect (extracted from this relevant [`blog post`](https://blog.genuine.com/2018/03/https-redirection-with-akka-http/)) should look something like below:

```
val route =
  scheme("http") {
    extract(_.request.uri) { uri =>
      redirect( uri.withScheme("https").withAuthority(hostName, portHttps),
        StatusCodes.MovedPermanently
      )
    }
  }
```

Note that `.withAuthority()` is not needed if you’re using standard HTTPS port (i.e. 443).

Comment: Gotcha, I just added one of my routes as an example, so I need to add what you put there? Well, really just add the scheme and then the complete after the redirect?

Comment: @Kooky_Lukey, similar to the sample code in the linked blog post, you can simply chain your other routes/path matchers, if any, using the tilde combinator (i.e. `~`).